# How to create a ViewModel event pattern

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a web application built using Knockout.js but the one thing I have failed to implement is proper reusable HTML.  Right now even if I have a view such as a dialog which is shared by multiple other views I have to copy and paste the HTML code and nest it in the parent in order to achieve proper binding communication between the child and parent.

Here's an example:

```
<div class="person-view"> <!-- PersonViewModel -->
    <div class="person-details">
        <!-- Person details -->
    </div>
    <button type="button" data-bind="click: EditAddress">Edit address</button>
    <div class="modal hide fade" role="dialog" data-bind="modal: ShowEditAddressModal, with: Address"> <!-- AddressViewModel -->
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3>Edit address</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <!-- Address details -->
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            <button class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" data-bind="click: function() { $parent.SetAddress($data); }">Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In this case I have a sub-ViewModel which I am setting as the DataContext for the modal div.  When the user clicks the Save button I am calling a method on the parent DataContext.

I know how to break the modal out to a separate HTML template and to generate the template dynamically supplying the ViewModel.  That would work for showing and hiding the modal because I would simply need to do the following from within the code of the parent:

`this.Address().IsShown(true);`

In this case the modal would simply bind its visibility to a property on itself and the parent just needs to change it.  That's fine.

However, what about when I click the **Save** button?  I do not see how to have the parent respond to this occurrence using the MVVM pattern of Knockout.js.  The button would still need a `click` binding which would bind to arbitrary code on the AddressViewModel, but how would it signal an event to its parent using Knockout?

Is there no way of doing this with Knockout and do I need to implement a separate library such as Underscore.js for events?

Comment: You probably need to use prototyping in your view / view model and pass in a callback to your view model.  That way you can instantiate it from any other view and have it call back to the parent whenever it closes.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but the problem you're trying to solve is eliminated by using a library like [DurandalJS](http://durandaljs.com) which is built on top of knockout and handles view composition. There are a lot of features that Durandal provides to enable the kind of code reuse you're looking for, without having to reinvent the wheel. It's not the right fit for every project, but it might fit your needs.